# Moving a vector element to the back of the vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Is there any better way (either faster or with fewer symbols of code) than erasing the element and re-adding it to the back?

```
template <typename T>
void moveItemToBack(std::vector<T>& v, size_t itemIndex)
{
   T tmp(v[itemIndex]);
   v.erase(v.begin() + itemIndex);
   v.push_back(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Not really...Vector is not a very efficient way to store things that need to be removed from the beginning. Look at `std::queue` or `std::dequeue`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: std::dequeue is no better here, and I need random access.

Comment: Then the efficient structure to use is to make your own ring buffer.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I didn't ask which container is best for this task, I asked what's the best possible way to do it with `vector`. Why the downvote?..

Comment: Sorry, the down-vote wasn't me (unfortunately, I've found a lot of stack overflow puts down-votes on "beginner" questions). The fact that I don't have a direct answer to your question is why I'm in the comments. A ring buffer would utilize a vector, be constant time to do this operation (which answers the "faster" part).

Comment: You also might try using [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). It will do what you want but I'm not sure if it would be faster or slower than `push_back/erase`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do this with [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) from the standard library. Since this doesn't change the vector size it also won't trigger a reallocation. Your function would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void moveItemToBack(std::vector<T>& v, size_t itemIndex)
{
    auto it = v.begin() + itemIndex;
    std::rotate(it, it + 1, v.end());
}
```

Comment: This is what Stepanov (designed the STL) recommends:  http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf , pg. 154.

Comment: Just a note: if I'm reading this correctly, this has O(n) complexity. The `std::swap` solution below has complexity O(1).

Comment: @imallett You're correct. This answer does preserve the order of elements other than the moved item while the other answer doesn't. The question, as stated, wasn't clear if that was a requirement. Preserving order is more costly.

Answer (score 13):

Possibly the fastest way, would be to swap it with the last element

```
template <typename T>
void moveItemToBack(std::vector<T>& v, size_t itemIndex)
{
   std::swap(v[itemIndex], v.back()); // or swap with *(v.end()-1)
}
```

**one operation!** Ofcourse `std::swap` has to work with `T`

Comment: It's an obvious solution, but it alters the ordering of items beyond simply moving one to the end.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe While rotate doesn't ?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe OK now got what you ment. It's OK to rotate as long as the relative order doesn't change. I was just giving a literal answer to the question "move one element to the back"

Comment: Of course, it's my mistake I didn't express all the requirements in my question. Your answer suits my question as currently stated.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the extra variable.

```
v.push_back(v[itemIndex]);
v.erase(v.begin() + itemIndex);
```

If you delete frequently from the middle of the vector and can rewrite your code so that it doesn't require random access, you may be able to improve efficiency by using a linked list (`std::list`) instead.

Comment: Ah, of course, neat! Thanks. BTW, is there any benefit to using `emplace_back` rather than `push_back` here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, if `T` is small, `emplace_back` is not likely to be faster than `push_back`. If `T` is large then I'm actually not sure.

Comment: @Brian emplace_back actually calls the constructor for the class, which would reduce to the copy constructor with this call...so in this case, I don't think it would matter for either. You could do `v.push_back(std::move(v[itemIndex))` to trigger using the move constructor in C++11.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, you're right, I was stupid for a moment there and thought `push_back` took its argument by value

Comment: There is a potential performance hit doing it this way. Doing `push_back` before the `erase` temporarily increases the vector's size and might cause a reallocation.