# Moving vector elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

I have a question concerning the resolution of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789498/moving-a-vector-element-to-the-back-of-the-vector). The answer suggest that moving an element of vector to back of the vector with using [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

However I believe that [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) would be a more appropriate solution. Since std::iter_swap works on an element whereas `std::rotate` works on the range.

```
template <typename T>
void moveItemToBack(std::vector<T>& v, size_t itemIndex)
{
    std::iter_swap(std::next(vec.begin(), itemIndex), v.end());
}
```

Comment: If you swap then the middle elements are now out of order. If you rotate, they are not. Two different solutions for two different problems. Choose whatever applies.

Comment: There is an answer that suggests this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23791868/407650 , and in the comments it is explained why it doesn't work.